# Let $f(x) = |x+1|-|x-1|$, find $f \circ f\circ f\circ f ... \circ f(x)$ (n times).

Tags: functions, absolute-value, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f(x) = |x+1|-|x-1|$, find $f \circ f\circ f\circ f ... \circ f(x)$  (n times). I don't know where to start... Should I use mathematical induction? But what should be my hypothesis? Should I calculate for n = 1, n = 2?

Comment: Have you tried composing several times to find a pattern?

Comment: Yep, graph the first four or five iterates.

Comment: I did, but I see no pattern. However graphing it shows that it's tending towards a signum function

Comment: I suppose we can use a piecewise function, using n and x as variables?

Comment: Yeah, I just graphed it too and that's what it looks like (much to my surprise). But you want a (closed form expression?) for $f^{(n)}$, so zoom in to the graph and figure out the central interval in terms of $n$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC OK - then  should get something like $$f^{n+1}(x) = \left|2^nx+1\right| - \left|2^nx-1\right|$$.

Comment: @HengWei - How rigorous does your answer need to be? Do you have to prove it, or is it enough to come up with a formula that seems to behave right?

Comment: I need to find what $f^n(x)$ is

Comment: i think it's going to be a piece wise function, with $f^n(x)$ equals -2, 2, and a function with an increasing slope

Comment: That sounds about right. You can post your own answer to your own question, so why don't you post what you've got so far for the piecewise function as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

First note
$$f(x) = |x+1| - |x-1|\\
= \begin{cases}
-2, & x< -1\\
2x, &  x\in [-1, 1] \\
2, &  x>1\\
\end{cases}$$

Proposition: $$\color{red}{f^{n+1}(x) = \left|2^nx+1\right| - \left| 2^nx-1\right|}$$.

Note: this is exactly equivalent to
$$f^{n+1}(x) = \begin{cases}
-2, & x< -\frac1{2^n}\\
2^{n+1}x, &  x\in [-\frac1{2^n}, \frac1{2^n}] \\
2, &  x>\frac1{2^n}\\
\end{cases}$$

Clearly true for $n=0$.  Assuming it holds for $n$, the inductive step is

$$f^{n+2}x = f\circ f^{n+1} (x)= \begin{cases}
f(-2), & x < -\frac1{2^n}\\
f(2^{n+1}x), &x\in [-\frac1{2^n}, \frac1{2^n}] \\
f(2), &  x>\frac1{2^n}\\  
\end{cases}\\
=\begin{cases}
-2, & x < -\frac1{2^n}\\
-2, &x\in [-\frac1{2^n}, -\frac1{2^{n+1}}) \\
f(2^{n+1}x), &x\in [-\frac1{2^{n+1}}, \frac1{2^{n+1}}] \\
2, &x\in (\frac1{2^{n+1}}, \frac1{2^n}] \\
2, &  x>\frac1{2^n}\\  
\end{cases}$$
$$=\begin{cases}
-2, & x < -\frac1{2^{n+1}} \\
2^{n+2}x, &x\in [-\frac1{2^{n+1}}, \frac1{2^{n+1}}] \\
2, &x > \frac1{2^{n+1}}\\  
\end{cases}\\
= |2^{n+1}x+1| - |2^{n+1}x-1|$$

Comment: As we say in California, that is both gnarly and impressive. +1 for the LaTeX alone.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC It's essentially a bunch of casework!

Comment: I always goof up trying to typeset piecewise definitions, so I'm impressed. Plus, I wasn't expecting to see a closed form.

Comment: awesome proof, thank you!

Comment: I have provided a different proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more general solution, introducing a "one-parameter" group of functions (see relationship (3)).

As function $f$ is odd, and the composition of odd functions is odd, we can restrict our study to positive values of $x$.

In this domain, we can express $f$ in the following way:

$$f(x)=\min(2x,2)$$

Let us introduce, for any $a>0$, the following notation:

$$f_a(x):=\min(2ax,2)\tag{1}$$

giving in particular $f_1=f \tag{2}.$

We have the identity (assuming $a,b \ge 1$):

$$f_{2ab}(x)=f_a(f_b(x))\tag{3}$$ from which, by an immediate recurrence, taking $a=b=1$, we get the desired answer:

$$f_{2^n}(x)=\underbrace{(f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f)}_{(n+1) \ \text{times "f"}}(x)$$

**Proof of (3)**: (3) is equivalent to:

$$\begin{align}
&&\forall x>0, \ \ &\min(4abx,2)=\min(2a.f_b(x),2)\\
&\iff &&\min(4abx,2)=\min([2a.\min(2bx,2)],2)\\
&\iff &&\min(4abx,2)=\min(4abx,4a,2)\end{align}$$

(by associativity of "min" operator)

proving (1) because we deal with values of $a$ which are $\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a graph of the first few iterates:

[image: iterates]

([Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7ru7foalia))